# If the command nullspace doesnt work on mathematica is there anything else that does the same thing?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix S(105 rows and 22 columns) and I need to find its orthogonal (when I multiply S with the orthogonal the result must be a zero matrix).I searched and the only command I found that seems to do what I want is nullspace[S] but the result is not the matrix I need.It is a matrix with 8 rows and 22 columns that it doesnt give me the result I want.I tried Transpose in case it got the matrix backwards but the multiplication cannot be done either.Is there anyone who knows about mathematica that can help me?Thanks.

Comment: I remember "orthogonal is inverse equals transpose", but lots of names have several incompatible definitions. Now a dumb simple method. Create matrix new of variables a1,a2,... with 22 rows and 105 columns, new/.Solve[ original.new==0,Flatten[ new ] ] and it should (may) find new for you. But when I try that with a random original the answer is always instantly the zero matrix, which seems obvious after I think a moment. Suggestion: Edit in a 3x5 matrix and brute force show there is a solution. Then someone can scale this up to 105x22 for you.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NullSpace.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understood your concept of an "orthogonal" matrix, which is usually defined differently. But if you are looking for a matrix T such that  T.S == {{0,0,....},...} then

T = NullSpace[Transpose[S]];

Unless your 105*22-dimensional matrix S is highly degenerate, there is no solution such that S.T==0.
In this case, T = Transpose[NullSpace[S]] will most likely render {}.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work.The result is a matrix that it doesnt confirm the equation T.S==0.